# Checkbox does does not work in VB.Net form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, checkbox

I have two `checkboxes` for two `groupboxes` to enable visibility or invisibility of each one at a time but somehow one is working(`chboNew`) the other one(`chboIssue`) doesn't! 
here is the code I have written for it, any help would be appreciated:

```
Private Sub chboIssue_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chboIssue.CheckStateChanged
    If chboIssue.Checked = True Then
        gbIssueSearch.Visible = True
        gbNewSearch.Visible = False
        chboNew.Checked = False
    ElseIf chboIssue.Checked = False Then
        gbIssueSearch.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chboNew_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chboNew.CheckStateChanged
    If chboNew.Checked = True Then
        gbNewSearch.Visible = True
        gbIssueSearch.Visible = False
        chboIssue.Checked = False
    ElseIf chboIssue.Checked = False Then
        gbNewSearch.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Also, avoid Hungarian Notation (where the name of a variable is prefixed with an abbreviation of its type), consider `issueCheckbox` or `issueIsSelected` instead of `chboIssue`).

Comment: @Dai when check `chboIssue` it doesn't show `gbIssueSearch` groupbox to me and same when I un-check it it does nothing, Weird is this that when `gbNewSearch` groupbbox is visible and I un-check `chboIssue` checkbox it hides `gbNewSearch` groupbox while it should hide `gbIssueSearch` groupbox!

Comment: @Dai I changed `chboIssue` checkbox to `IssueCheckbox` but still it doesn't work! any other clue???

Comment: John DeFauw's answer will likely solve your problem (you are testing the status of chboIssue.Checked in both ElseIf, which seems wrong).  But you should heed Ashish Kamat's advice, and use radio buttons instead of checkboxes, so the users don't hate you.

Comment: Use a single checkbox.  `GrpBox1.Visible = checkbox.checked` and  `GrpBox2.Visible = Not checkbox.checked`  or reverse the logic depening on what the text says.  And it is usually better if you just disable them so the user has a cue that they *can* do something different there

Comment: thank you @Plutonix for the idea I will apply the logic of it somewhere else in my project when needed ;)

Comment: 2 radios are the same as the check/not checked state of a checkbox  but with fewer events to manage

Comment: Yes I agree with your answer but I think Radio buttons are more User friendly then checkbox when user only needs one from two @Plutonix ;)

Comment: In my case I need two options so I went for radiobuttons but when I need my user to select/deselect an option I will for sure use your advice @Plutonix (y)

Comment: `Radio buttons are more User friendly` I disagree - I cant remember the last time I saw a RadioButton except in older apps.  If there are 2 options a checkbox would fine,  For 3 or more a ComboBox takes less room and has one set of events vs say, 5 for radio button.  There are cases when they are a good idea, but it is sort of specialized

Comment: Ok Sir @Plutonix point noted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If user has to choose between new issue and issue search,one at a time.
Then you should use radio buttons, instead of checkbox.

Checkbox gives idea that user can choose both checkboxes at same time.
Which in your case is not true.

Comment: thank you it was very easy for me and I guess it would be very easy for the user as well to use the radio buttons and now my code works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of the checkboxes is not going to solve your issue. I noticed that for your chboNew.CheckStateChanged event handler in your elseif clause you are checking if chboIssue is checked, whereas in your other handler for chboIssue both your if/else clauses look at chboIssue. I'm thinking that may be part of your issue. Also, if only one of these boxes is supposed to be checked at a time, you may want to add logic to automatically uncheck the other whenever one is checked. For instance, in your chboNew handler, "If chboNew.Checked = True Then chboIssue = False", and the inverse in your chboIssue handler. Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you I fixed the first part you mentioned and the second part you mentioned is already there, I guess there might be some other problem cause I removed code from both handlers but still when I load my form it doesn't show the groupbox!

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  What code did you remove, exactly?  Which groupbox are you talking about?  Which checkbox is checked?